# Lowering elevation of lake using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, stl

I am in QGIS.

I have a raster layer of mountains and a lake.

I have a vector layer (shapefile) of the lake. It sits nicely where it supposed to be over the raster level.

I am going to convert this height map to an STL so that I can cnc this out of wood, so I'd like the actual lake to be something like 200 feet lower than it shows on the raster layer so that I can fill it with blue epoxy.

I have read a lot of clipping and everything else, and I am lost.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest the following 2 options:

#1: In the attribute table of the vector layer, make a new column called "value", and give a -200 value to the column (or any other value that you want to assign as a new depth/height).

- Convert your polygon to a raster. You can do this with the Rasterize tool (raster>conversion>rasterize).
- Make sure the new raster's pixel value is assigned the -200 value.
- Also make sure the cell size of the raster matches that of your DEM/Height map.  Is the height map in feet or other value?
- There are several ways you can merge the two rasters afterwards, but I suggest you have a look at the "Mosaic Raster Layer" tool to merge the two rasters. make sure that the "overlapping Areas" is set to Minimum, to ensure that the lake area is lowered to the new pixel value.

#2:
I have tested the following plugin, called **Serval Plugin**.  It works great and would be very easy to manipulate your raster.
[image]

- You can load your Height Model and simply make a selection of your layer (lake surrounding),  and directly edit the raster value to -200.

More about the toolbar you can find here: https://www.giscourse.com/editing-dem-pixels-values-in-qgis-using-serval-plugin/

After installing the plugin, restart QGIS and make sure your Height Model is in a "standard" coordinate system, like WGS84,  you can use the warp tool to convert to a different system if needed.

Comment: You were awesome here, but I have one more question. If I have roads in a shapefile, I am not able to lower the raster pixels like the lake. How can I do this?

Comment: I think you need to create a polygon dataset of your roads first.  Perhaps you can create a buffer around your road dataset,  use something like 2 meters for example. The tool works with area information so probably it works better if you convert it like that first. Hope it works!

Answer (score 3):

so I found a solution on my own too using the Raster Calculator from the Raster menu.

1. I clipped my raster to the shapefile I wanted using the "Clip raster by mask layer from GDAL:

[image: Showing Clip raster by mask layer tool]

2. I opened the raster calculator:

[image: Showing the raster calculator in the raster menu]

3. Then I double-clicked the raster I wanted to modify and typed "-200" in the calculator and my expression became "'Clipped (mask)@1'-200 " :

[image: Expression]

4. Make sure you assign an address and name in Output Layer on the top right of the Raster Calculator window:

[image: Name output]

5. Press OK, and result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange.com. Merging may be needed afterward as PGerrits has mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Serval Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Serval/) worked really well for this problem.  It has a nice [tutorial](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/serval/blob/master/Serval/docs/user_manual.md) on it's help page.