# Manually changing elevation data of DEM using QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation

I'm looking to do personal modifications to a DEM (Aster global elevation model).

I want to select an rectangular area & reduce its recorded elevation by 20m.

There are other parts on my map I want to raise in elevation, but I think if I learn how to reduce, I will be able to do the process in reverse and increase the elevation.

Is this possible?

Comment: You might want to look into tools that will allow you to manually modify any raster dataset. That might be more likely than a tool just for DEMs.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is a raster, I gave the answer in a similar question:

[How do I lower to elevation of a lake?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388563/how-do-i-lower-to-elevation-of-a-lake/388570#388570)

I actually clipped the area that I wanted to change elevation so it might apply to your cause similarly.